# I am overriding a controller and want to use a custom helper in the overrided controller,how can i?

Tags: overrides, controllers, magento-2.2.5

I've overridden following controller:-

```
Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost.php
```

And the constructor method of this class is:-

```
 public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->addressHelper = $addressHelper;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->regionDataFactory = $regionDataFactory;
        $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
        $this->customerDataFactory = $customerDataFactory;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->registration = $registration;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
        $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

I'm trying to call helper in my overridden controller which is:-

```
INW\VendorRequest\Controller\Magento\Customer\Account\CreatePost.php
```

And I tried two different way and here is my constructor code:-

**1-**

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        \INW\ReviewMail\Helper\Data $helper, // MY HELPER WHICH I'M INJECTING
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->addressHelper = $addressHelper;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->regionDataFactory = $regionDataFactory;
        $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
        $this->customerDataFactory = $customerDataFactory;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->registration = $registration;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
        $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
          $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

**2-**

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
   \INW\ReviewMail\Helper\Data $helper
) {
     $this->_helper = $helper;
}
```

But I'm getting the issue which you can see in the screenshot:-

[image]

Please let me know, how to inject helper, blocks in the overridden controller.

-----------Updated------------------

Already flush cache removed generated folder but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

When you override a model, helper or controller. The parent constructor has to be used within the overridden object (as per your suggestion number 1)

- essentially, the hurdle you have managed to avoid is to put your dependency injection above optional parameters (parameters that can be null)
- now, what you seem to face is that Magento will need the generated folder to be emptied if you have changed the signature of an object in your custom code

In short, do flush the cache and clear generated folder should help with your problem

Comment: thanks for the update...sorry i forget to mention that i already removed generated folder and flush the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've resolved the issue...I've to inject parent class parameters into parent::__construct(),here  is the detail:-

```
<?php

namespace INW\VendorRequest\Controller\Magento\Customer\Account;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Address;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;

use INW\ReviewMail\Helper\Data as HelperData; //New Helper@this is not in parent class

class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{

        public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null,

        HelperData $helperData
    ) {
        $this->_helperData = $helperData;

        parent::__construct($context,$customerSession,$scopeConfig,$storeManager,$accountManagement,$addressHelper,$urlFactory,$formFactory,$subscriberFactory,$regionDataFactory,$addressDataFactory,$customerDataFactory,$customerUrl,$registration,$escaper,$customerExtractor,$dataObjectHelper,$accountRedirect,$formKeyValidator); // this is the right way to override parent classes.

        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);    

        $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();

    }
}
```